# How can I specify the regional date format?

Tags: java, string, date, timezone

When I convert a date to a string at java and applies the following pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

output : 2016-07-14

But I want to be as follows.

```
Japan, Korea user : 2016-07-14
USA, Canada user : 07-14-2016
Germany, Australia user : 14-07-2016
```

I can set pattern "if~else", looking for a more general way.
How can i that?

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna use Locale

```
Locale locale = Locale.KOREA; // select any locale you want
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);

System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
String output = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) );
```

## Details

The Question and other Answers are using old outmoded classes (SimpleDateFormat, Date, Calendar, etc.).

Instead use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To get the current date, you need a time zone. For any given moment the date various around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

To get standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD, call `toString`.

```
String output = today.toString();
```

To [localize the format and content](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) of the String being generated to represent the date value, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine the length (Full, Long, Medium, Short).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT );
```

Assign a specific [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) rather than your JVM’s current default.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
String output = today.format( formatter );
```

That's it, quite simple. Just define a `Locale` as needed, such as `Locale.CANADA`, `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`, `Locale.GERMANY`, `Locale.KOREA`, or use the various constructors where you pass the human language, and optionally the country and variant.

Answer (score 0):

try this from [http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/FourdifferentdateformatsforfourcountriesUSUKGERMANYFRANCE.htm ]

```
import static java.util.Locale.*;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date today = new Date();
        Locale[] locales = { US, UK, GERMANY, FRANCE,JAPAN };
        int[] styles = { FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT };
        String[] styleNames = { "FULL", "LONG", "MEDIUM", "SHORT" };
        DateFormat fmt = null;
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
          System.out.println("\nThe Date for " + locale.getDisplayCountry() + ":");
          for (int i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            fmt = DateFormat.getDateInstance(styles[i], locale);
            System.out.println("\tIn " + styleNames[i] + " is " + fmt.format(today));
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Japan, Korea user : 2016-07-14
    SimpleDateFormat korea = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    // USA, Canada user : 07-14-2016
    SimpleDateFormat usa = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    // Germany, Australia user : 14-07-2016
    SimpleDateFormat europe = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    System.out.println("Japan, Korea user : " + korea.format(new Date()));
    System.out.println("USA, Canada  user : " + usa.format(new Date()));
    System.out.println("Germany, Australia user : " + europe.format(new Date()));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Japan, Korea user : 2016-07-14
USA, Canada  user : 07-14-2016
Germany, Australia user : 14-07-2016
```